# can i modify the color of emacs mini buffer?

Tags: emacs

i like emacs in terminal,but the blue color of mini buffer is hard to see clearly.

really need it,thanks for help!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this,

```
(set-face-foreground 'minibuffer-prompt "white")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't stand your terminal's blue color, you can probably change it. The different terminal emulators have different tools for this, but most use X resources.

My own personal color choices for urxvt:

```
URxvt.background:       #000000
URxvt.foreground:       gray75
URxvt.color3:           DarkGoldenrod
URxvt.color4:           RoyalBlue
URxvt.color11:          LightGoldenrod
URxvt.color12:          LightSteelBlue
URxvt.color7:           gray75
URxvt.colorBD:          #ffffff
URxvt.colorUL:          LightSlateGrey
URxvt.colorIT:          SteelBlue
URxvt.cursorColor:      grey90
URxvt.highlightColor:   grey25
```

But of course, your own terminal emulator of choice may have a different class (URxvt) or application (urxvt, not used in my example) name, and the resource names may be different as well. urxvt will use color names (from the server's rgb.txt file -- use `xcolorsel(1)` to see them in a handy application) or numbers, but other terminals may not be this flexible.

From my `xterm(1)` manpage, the colors and their numbers are:

```
0  black
1  red3
2  green3
3  yellow3
4  a customizable dark blue
5  magenta3
6  cyan3
7  gray90

8  gray30
9  red
10 green
11 yellow
12 a customizable light blue
13 magenta
14 cyan
15 white
```

If your terminal does use X resources, save your desired resources to a file (by convention named `~/.Xdefaults` or `~/.Xresources`) and use `xrdb -merge <filename>` to load your resources into the server. Then start your terminal again, and try it out.

If your terminal uses some other mechanism to configure color choices (perhaps it has a Preferences menu item or something similar), it will probably still have different colors listed somewhere, and you'll need to change colors 4 and 12 to change the blue color.

On the other hand, if you like the blue for everything *except* emacs, you can either try to get emacs to use a different color (no idea there, sorry), or you can run your terminal emulator with a different "class", so it will read different X resources. (`xterm(1)` has a `-class` parameter for this.)

Comment: thanks for your detail answer.i use LXDE terminal on mint linux.don't have the dir you said.it's better make emacs to change color.if cannot, your answer is a new option.

Comment: Hrm, I'm not sure LXTerminal will let you pick other colors; it claims to be VTE based, and http://people.redhat.com/nalin/vte/html/vteterminal.html#VTE-TERMINAL-SET-COLORS has a description for how to change the color palette with no mentions of where it gets defaults, so I assume they must be changed programmatically. The LXTerminal screenshot on http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTerminal doesn't show a color-palette selector widget, so it might not be possible.

Check the docs and hope for the best. :)

Comment: i find ~/.config/lxterminal/ have a config file, it really works.

i have to change the bgcolor of terminal to white to display the emacs blue font. i really like the black terminal feeling.

Comment: Ah, the price of minimalism: http://www.gnomefiles.org/app.php/LxTerminal  "2. Support customizing foreground and background color" No mention of the whole color palette. Feel free to use any other terminal emulator, I suggest urxvt, but xterm, rxvt, aterm, wterm, Eterm, xfce4-terminal, xvt, mlterm, kterm, konsole, gnome-terminal are all popular choices, and most (if not all) will let you change color4 and color12. Or you can file a feature request with the LXDE team.

Comment: lxterminal has multi tab. others seems not.

Comment: what about DOS Prompt? I use it in my Windows Seven workstation.

Comment: @swdev, I think Windows DOS boxes let you change the color scheme if you single-click on the box on the upper-left-corner of the window. It will give you a menu of commands, and among the usual select/cut/copy/paste there will be one for window size and _hopefully_ one for colors, too.